# How do I make a Make, Make Install, and deb file for a python program?

Tags: software-installation, python, make, deb, debian-installer

I recently wrote a python program. Now the question: how do I go about making an installation script for it? From my understanding, you need to create a make file, I believe that a make file is made for *compiled* languages, not *interpreted* languages.

What must I do to make an installation script for my python program?

Comment: you use `make`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to package your application for installation on Debian systems, your best starting point is the `dh-python` package.

You may also find the [Debian Python FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/FAQ), [The Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/creation.html) and the Python [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) useful references.